# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php

im doing this project for my php class I have included the code. I cannot figure out what the syntax error is. I have changed things many times but nothing works. Can someone help me. thanks!

```
<title>ordering form</title>
</head>

<body>


<h1>Welcome  <?php echo $_POST['firstname']; ?> </h1>

<?php
if($_POST['sport'] == "gymnastics" && $_POST['gender'] == "men")
{
echo "You do not fit your category";
}
elseif($_POST['sport'] == "football" && $_POST['gender'] == "women")
{
echo "You do not fit your category";
}
else
{
echo "You fit your category"; 
}
?>
<?php
$mugcost = 4.95;
$taxrate = .08;
$mugcost = $mugcost * $_POST['quantity'];
$tax = $mugcost * $taxrate;
$mugcost = $mugcost + $tax;
$shipping = 5.99;
$finalcost = $shipping + $mugcost;
?>
<?php
echo "Your total cost is," $finalcost;  
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `echo "Your total cost is,"<PROBLEM HERE> $finalcost;`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error

Comment: General tip: If you get an error message, tell us WHERE the error occurs. PHP gives you line numbers. Point out that line to us. Don't make us read through your wall of code and try to count lines ourselves.

Comment: @MikeB You're right, it must be off topic because it mentions syntax errors shouldn't be asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Oh wait, no it doesn't. Well it must be excluded [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It's not? Darn.

Comment: @Jason There's lots more reading you need to do http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160275/are-questions-about-syntax-errors-too-localized and all the dupes. I've been part of SO for almost 5 years and syntax questions have always been unwelcome because the crowd they bring don't meet the requirements detailed in the FAQ. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+syntax+error+is%3Aquestion It's not like this is something new.

Comment: I don't tend to troll, but setting you off was rather fulfilling. I've been a user for 5 months, and apparently they don't care about it as much as you think they do, because they didn't add it to their help section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to properly concatenate this line (now with a brand new `.`):

```
<?php
echo "Your total cost is," . $finalcost;  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing  string concatenate operator (`.`)

```
<?php
    echo "Your total cost is," .$finalcost;  
                               ^
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In you're last `echo` you're missing a period:

```
echo "Your total cost is,". $finalcost;
                          ^^
```

Comment: oh ok thank you so much I spent hours trying to figure this out on something so easy. thank you